# How can I convert large RTF string to HTML string manually in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have large RTF string read from a document and I need to display it on an ASP.NET (.cshtml) page. How can I convert it to HTML manually without using any nuget packages or class libraries before displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to read RTF documents in C# / .NET.

If you can't (or don't want to) use any libraries the only thing you can do is to implement the [RTF specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm), and output html based on the resulting parsed document. (But I'd just use a library, there's one doing exactly what you want: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RtfPipe/)

Comment: Are there any C# source code (class) which convert to HTML according to RTF Specification?

Comment: the project I mentioned is open source https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe